# Why does the session expires when i close the browser Mozila and IE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have this Session:

```
Session.Add("Lastname", data.LastName);
Session.Add("Firstname", data.FirstName);
Session.Add("AuthorID", data.AuthorID);
```

When I close the browser the session expires in both Mozilla and IE
but when I tested it in Chrome, after closing the browser it does not expire.

Is there some code to prevent session from expiring when the browser is closed (for Mozilla and IE)?

Comment: What is your reason to believe that session expires? Do you understand how cookies work?

Comment: or they just clearing the session after i close the browser?? is there a possible way to prevent that?

Comment: Since there are 2 "session" involved there - yes, browsers close browser session (and drop all session cookies), no closing browser have no impact on `Session` (also you'll have hard time joining the same `Session`... but it is still there).

Comment: is there some sort of code to get it back again?

Comment: Sure... I'd start with playing with Fiddler to capture cookie and than set it again after restarting browser. Clearly can be automated... Note that server side session will expire due to inactivity at some point, so you'd need to get back quickly (I think default is 20 minutes). Or you mean server side code?

Comment: ok thank you can you give me a sample code for that? dont have an idea .